# Retrieving my dynamoDB data to Flutter app

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-dynamodb

How can I retrieve my data from my dynamoDB and display them onto my flutter application?

I've tried looking a lot over the net but can't possibly find something to try on.

It is about displaying temperature sensor data that are being stored in the tables.

Can someone suggest something please?

Thank you.

Comment: Try official amplify package for flutter. You would need to put AWS API Gateway in front of your dynamoDB - possibly even lambda in between: Api GW->Lambda->DynamoDB. Flutter amplify library gives you nice and easy way of accessing your AWS backend and fetching the data: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/flutter

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy.

1. First add [this](https://pub.dev/packages/aws_dynamodb_api) package to your project.
2. Then create your models you want to read and write. Along with conversion methods.

```dart
class Parent {
   String name;
   late List<Child> children;

 
  factory Parrent.fromDBValue(Map<String, AttributeValue> dbValue) {
    name = dbValue["name"]!.s!;
    children = dbValue["children"]!.l!.map((e) =>Child.fromDB(e)).toList();
  }


  Map<String, AttributeValue> toDBValue() {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> dbMap = Map();
    dbMap["name"] = AttributeValue(s: name);
    dbMap["children"] = AttributeValue(
        l: children.map((e) => AttributeValue(m: e.toDBValue())).toList());
    return dbMap;
  }
}
```

(AttributeValue comes from the package)

Then you can consume dynamo db api as per normal.

3. Create Dynamo service

```dart
class DynamoService {
  final service = DynamoDB(
      region: 'af-south-1',
      credentials: AwsClientCredentials(
          accessKey: "someAccessKey",
          secretKey: "somesecretkey"));

  Future<List<Map<String, AttributeValue>>?> getAll(
      {required String tableName}) async {
    var reslut = await service.scan(tableName: tableName);
    return reslut.items;
  }

  Future insertNewItem(Map<String, AttributeValue> dbData, String tableName) async {
    service.putItem(item: dbData, tableName: tableName);
  }
}
```

Then you can convert when getting all data from dynamo.

```dart
List<Parent> getAllParents() {
   List<Map<String, AttributeValue>>? parents =
        await dynamoService.getAll(tableName: "parents");
  return parents!.map((e) =>Parent.fromDbValue(e)).toList()
}
```

You can check all Dynamo operations from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.ReadItem.html)

Comment: Do you know how to correct the clock skew with this aws_dynamodb_api package, it's not possible, this is a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Terblanche Daniel answer, note that scan returns a maximum of 1 MB of data.

It is necessary to rerun the scan if lastEvaluatedKey is set.

```
  do {
    var result = await service.scan(
        exclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey,
        tableName: tableName);
    lastEvaluatedKey = result.lastEvaluatedKey;
    items.addAll(result.items ?? []);
  } while (lastEvaluatedKey != null);
```